# what will be the equivalent angular 2 code for angular js code below?

Tags: angular

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "welcome.htm"
  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

iam bit confused how to bind the data of the html file to the variable while writing in angular code...can you please me by giving and and a little bit explanation.

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: Have you tried something? Try to convert it to Angular 2 first by yourself

Comment: yeah... iam confusing regarding binding $scope.myWelcome = response.data;

Comment: `$scope` doesn't exist any more in Angular. Again, read the tutorial.

Comment: i know that.....if u know just write code and explain...or leave it..don't again tell me to read tutorial

Comment: i told you iam confusing and  you r again telling me to read tutorial..its unfair

Answer (score 1):

With Angular you'd be required to have a `*.component.html`, `*.component.ts` and `*.module.ts`.

In your `*.component.ts` you would have the following:

```
import {...} from '...';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  public myWelcome: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  ngOnInit() {
    let url = 'whatever url you need';
    this.http.get<any>(url)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.myWelcome = response.data;
        //Handle success
      }, error => {
        //Handle error
      });
  }
}
```

The `HttpClient` would do the HTTP GET to fetch the data. The response value would then be stored on the `myWelcome` variable and can be used inside you HTML.

In your `*.component.html`

```
<h1>{{myWelcome?}}</h1>
```

The `?` is there incase the value is null, it won't break your page.

That's the basics of how you would do this in Angular